# ¿Cómo puedo centrar el título de un acordeon? Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap

[image: Problema]

La idea es que "Pago en línea quede en el centro y el boton siga quedándose siempre a la derecha.
Acá les dejo el código para que vean.

```html
<div class="accordion accordion-flush justify-content-around container-fluid" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header text-center" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed panel-title" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        Pago en línea
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <h5>PAGO EN LÍNEA</h5>
        <p>Podés pagar con tu tarjeta Visa, MasterCard o American Express, ¡Con ellas podrás pagar hasta 3 cuotas sin asumir el interés bancario! También es posible efectuar tu pago con Pago Fácil y Rapipago.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar un `div` que encierre al texto, darle un ancho del 100% para luego centrarlo con las siguientes propiedades:

```
.centrar{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Tu código sería el siguiente:

```css
.centrar{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="accordion accordion-flush justify-content-around container-fluid p-4" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header text-center" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed panel-title" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        <div class="centrar">
          Pago en línea
        </div>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <h5>PAGO EN LÍNEA</h5>
        <p>
          Podés pagar con tu tarjeta Visa, MasterCard o American Express, ¡Con
          ellas podrás pagar hasta 3 cuotas sin asumir el interés bancario!
          También es posible efectuar tu pago con Pago Fácil y Rapipago.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O también, sin css, con solo las clases que te proporciona bootstrap:

```
class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center"
```

En donde:

```
// w-100 => le damos un ancho al 100%
// d-flex => convierte el elemento en flexible
// justify-content-center => justificar al centro
```

Y el código sería el siguiente:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="accordion accordion-flush justify-content-around container-fluid p-4" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header text-center" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed panel-title" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
          Pago en línea
        </div>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <h5>PAGO EN LÍNEA</h5>
        <p>
          Podés pagar con tu tarjeta Visa, MasterCard o American Express, ¡Con
          ellas podrás pagar hasta 3 cuotas sin asumir el interés bancario!
          También es posible efectuar tu pago con Pago Fácil y Rapipago.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Toma el texto "Pago en linea" (el que tenes en el accordion-button), envuélvelo en un `<h5>` y le das un margin-start-auto:

```
<h5 class="ms-auto">Pago en línea</h5>
```